# Не работает редактирование своего комментария в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект

Не работает редактирование своего комментария в очереди проверок. Выводится сообщение об ошибке, что правка невозможна. Комментарий был написан в той же очереди.

При открытии вопроса в отдельной вкладке, комментарий изменить получилось.

[Комментарий](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507285/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-radiobutton-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-jquery#comment612087_507285)
[Проверка в очереди](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/71058)

Comment: У меня не воспроизвелось, но это не показатель

Comment: @NickVolynkin, у меня тоже не воспроизводится. Но точно уже не первый раз с этой проблемой столкнулся. Может, надо вопрос, закрываемый как копия?